# VKontakte api, новая авторизация access_token (php)

Tags: php, вконтакте, vkontakte-api, curl

Вопрос насущный..бьюсь уже сутки..
VKontakte запустили новый метод авторизации через `access_token`, все бы ничего, научился работать с новым методом, однако, процесс загрузки фотографий на сервер вконтакте описан [здесь](http://vkontakte.ru/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5).

Получил я сервер для загрузки фотографий `cs11183.vkontakte.ru` (полет нормальный, первый пункт выполнили). Далее нужно отправить на этот сервер фотографию методом POST в моем случае через CURL. Неужели я не должен где-то отправить `access_token`? Для передачи фотографии на сервер ничего не нужно? Вот что пишут вконтакте`

---

```
2. Приложение формирует POST-запрос на полученный адрес.
Запрос должен содержать поля file1-file5, которые содержат файлы с изображениями (JPG, PNG, BMP или GIF). `
```

---

Естественно ничего не выходит... Кто писал мануал для контакта? Они хотят, чтобы мы умерли?

Answer (score 2):

[Здесь](http://vkontakte.ru/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BA_API) описано как взаимодействовать с API,

адрес*апи/добавить*фото?параметры&access_token=...

и будет вам счастье.

Ну а на счет мануалов для контакта - да, кладут большой хук на разработчиков, посмотрите хотя бы на ответы для получения списка видео :)